# duplicity + rsync still backup excluded files with --rsync-options

Tags: linux, rsync, duplicity

By using the command below, I intended to exclude three types of an archive with a name that consists of Backup, however, the files still get copied. Any idea what's the mistake?

```
   duplicity --encrypt-key somekey --verbosity 8 --rsync-options "-avPt --delete --delete-excluded --exclude="*Backup*."{zip,tar,xz} --include="*/" --include="*" --rsync-path="sudo rsync"" source dest
```

I realize the `--exclude` flag from `duplicity` exist, but `rsync`'s more suit to my needs (multiple combinations of the flags achieve what I want). This will only be my last resort if using rsync's own flag is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

duplicity will only use your `--rsync-options` if your destination url has the form `rsync://...`.

Also, the command you give above is using double-quotes inside double-quotes, which may not work as you intended. Looking at the sources, in [backend.py](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/duplicity/0.8-series/view/head:/duplicity/backend.py#L489) we see that python [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) is used to parse the command line that you provide via `--rsync-options`. It seems therefore that you can use single quotes to quote each separate argument, including the one with spaces: `--rsync-path='sudo rsync'`.